# Can TestCafe follow a sequence through multiple pages?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am very new to TestCafe, (but excited by what I see) so this might be a dumb mistake.
All the examples of TestCafe that I have found, depend on a single URL.
However, I want to test a very familiar sequence:

1. user makes some choices in page X and clicks submit,
2. user is shown multiple matching records in page Y, and clicks something in one result,
3. user sees a detail page Z, with full information for one record

When I try this in TestCafe, my test terminates when control leaves X. It never sees Y.
So, in the last lines of my test, after it submits page X

```
   await t 
      .click(submitButton);
```

.. if I look for values which should be in page Y,

```
   await t 
      .expect(Selector('#back-to-home-page').innerText)
      .contains ('Back to Page X');
```

the Selector cannot find them. It only finds things still in page X.
(I have testcafe v 6.14, but this is not version-specific).
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand your question precisely, is page Y a different page that opens? (eg. you click on submit and page Y opens in a new tab / window)
See this for that: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/multiple-browser-windows.html

Also, judging by the last sample you provided, it might be the case that the element doesn't load fast enough?

Try something like:

```
   await t 
  .expect(Selector('#back-to-home-page').innerText).contains('Back to Page X', {timeout: 20000})
```

See if the element is actually there before testcafe expects it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for that idea Liviu.
My case is only in a single window, not multiple windows or tabs. Page X and Y are different URLS on the same domain: a form then a search results page. A completely typical flow.

I tried your good suggestion, but it did not work and now I know why.

For reasons unknown so far, the Page X submit button remains disabled even after TestCafe completes the required inputs. It is visible but greyed out. With human entry, this does not happen, only with TestCafe data entry. Some piece of JQuery validation is not getting triggered.

As  newbie, before this, I did not know for sure if Testcafe could follow from page X to Page Y in any case, which would be an awful limitation. But I now have proved to myself that works, when I use TestCafe on other sites.
I can't solve the JQuery on my test site, and it is too detailed to post here. But I am happy to close the question.

Thank you guys.